# CheckBox to be set based on vale passed from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

New to the MVC Razor format and and a little stumped on why Im getting the result i have listed below. What my goal is to check and uncheck the checkbox in my view. When the page is submitted it will send the values to the controller and update the database based on what was checked. Its to activate and deactivate users.

Really simple all I want is the value to save True(box checked)/False(box unchecked).

Here is the one that works but I cant get it to stay checked when I revisit the page when the value is true.

```
@Html.CheckBox("UserStatus", false) <i>(check to deactivate)</i><br/>
```

This one I get an error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions*

```
@if (Convert.ToBoolean(Model.UserStatus == true))
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Convert.ToBoolean(model.UserStatus), new { @checked = "checked" })
}
else
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Convert.ToBoolean(model.UserStatus), false)
}
```

This one will always return false if its never been true in the database

```
<input id="UserStatus" name="UserStatus" @Html.Raw((Convert.ToBoolean(Model.UserStatus) == true ?  "checked='checked' value='true'" : "checkbox='' value='false'")) type="checkbox" />
```

Here is the controller

```
// GET: Employee/Delete/5
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    TEmployee User = db.TEmployees.Find(id);
    if (User == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(User);
}//End of Delete GET
```

Here is the models class

```
public partial class TEmployee
{
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> UserStatus { get; set; }
}
```

If you need more information or code please let me know.
any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: *Here is the one that works but I cant get it to stay checked when I revisit the page*, but you gave us the `HttpPost` method.  You need to provide the `HttpGet` method.  `HttpPost` should have nothing to do with the values on page load.

Comment: Sorry I Updated it.

Comment: Try changing this `@Html.CheckBox("UserStatus", false)` to `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.UserStatus)`

Comment: What type  is `UserStatus`?  If it's a bool, or bit in the database.. why are you converting to boolean?

Comment: @GTown-Coder it throws an error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Okay, can you post your `TEmployee` class? And you're sure that the record you are wanting to see has a value of `true` in the database?

Comment: @GTown-Coder because its set to null right away in the database so you have null, true,false.

Comment: Why can't you give `UserStatus` a default value then?  Makes things easier.. so in your example.. either a user is active or deactive

Comment: This is a feature that is being added later in the process or i would have set it up that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157583/discussion-between-gtown-coder-and-whisk).

Comment: It also might be important to note that when you use `@Html.CheckBoxFor` Razor will generate a checkbox and a hidden field to store the value. A checkbox doesn't really have a value ... it has a _state_. The modelbinder uses the hidden field to bind the value to your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so first off with `bit` and/or `bool` properties.. default values are the way to go, or at least **don't allow nulls** this way you will always have a value of either true or false.  Since `bit/bool` only consist of `0` or `1` (false or true), you shouldn't allow nulls because then it gives the `bit/bool` 3 values to consider.

Then once you set a default value, instead of using `@Html.CheckBox`.. use `@Html.CheckBoxFor` this way the property is strongly typed to your model in the view.  Also, in my opinion it looks cleaner and easier to maintain.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.UserStatus)
```

Furthermore, once you set a default value then you don't need to worry about `Convert.ToBoolean`.

Happy coding!